# How to model in idl for DDS

Tags: data-distribution-service

I am new to DDS and IDL, and i hope that somebody can provide some advice on how to model the following in IDL.

This is based on a model from a OO perspective, and it is just intended as a quick example:
[image]

And this is my initial datamodel in IDL - is done correctly?
How do I "model" inheritance and dependencies in IDL? a lot of the examples online are very simple - too simple the ones I have found...

```
module test{
struct carpool{
    long id; //@key
    string name;
    sequence<car> cars;
};

struct car{
    long id; //@key
    string color;
};
////the following inherits from car
struct sedan{
    string extra_equipment;
};

struct station_car{
    integer number_of_doors;
};
};
```

This is just a made up *example* of inheritance, and properly not the best ;o)

Is this correct or is there a better way of modelling the same - can anyone provide a link to a good "HOWTO" for working with IDL for DDS?
Note: I am working with RTI Connext DDS

Comment: Good question -- I will answer if I understand a bit better the exact intention of the inheritance tree. In your model, the purpose of the derived classes `Toyota` and `Mazda` is not clear. Why not move the `model` attribute into the `Car` class? If you do so, then `Toyota` and `Mazda` are no longer needed (from a data-distribution perspective). Or did you not show the complete data-model and are there other attributes or classes?

Comment: The code above is just an made up *example* of inheritance, and properly not the best - I have edited it a bit and hopefully it makes more sense now. Overall I am just trying to get a better understanding of IDL and how to take a OO model and "translate" that into IDL. I don't have a actual model right now - just trying to get a better understanding of DDS and IDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects in your IDL that deserve some attention.

First there is the inheritance mechanism, which was traditionally not supported by DDS, but is now by virtue of the [Extensible and Dynamic Topic Types](http://www.omg.org/spec/DDS-XTypes/) specification. The snippet below shows how to use that. However, whether or not you actually need that inheritance mechanism depends on how you are going to use the data. Do you ever intend to subscribe to the base-class `car`, or will you only subscribe to the derived classes? In the first case, you will need the true inheritance. In the second case, you can model inheritance by means of embedding the car base-structure into all derived cars.

Then there is also the matter of your one-to-many relationship between the `carpool` and `car` classes. Using a sequence is typically not the best approach. Suppose that you add  single car to your `carpool`, then as a result the whole `carpool` structure, with all its cars, will need to be republished. This might be what you want, but typically, it is better to use a "foreign key" on the `car` class to refer to the `carpool` it belongs to. This is much like the way regular database designs work as well. With this approach, the application is responsible for re-constructing the full carpool with the cars by relating them via the `carpoolId` attribute. Updates to the `carpool` then happen via the `car` structures. This does require the `car` to be aware of the `carpool` it belongs to though.

Possible example snippet:

```
module test {

  struct carpool {
    long   id; //@key
    string name;
  };

  struct car {
    long   id; //@key
    long   carpoolId; // refers to carpool this car belongs to
    string color;
  };

  struct sedan : car {
    string extra_equipment;
  };

  struct station_car : car {
    integer number_of_doors;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The new DDS Extensible Type specification introduced support for stucture inheritance in IDL. If you are working with RTI Connext DDS version 5.0.0 or later you can already take advantage of this feature.

The syntax would be:

```
struct car {
    long id; //@key
    string color;
};

struct sedan : car {
    string extra_equipment;
};

struct station_car : car {
    integer number_of_doors;
};
```

And so forth...

Gerardo